# Can't align navbar centrally

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm trying to make my navbar be central on my site, but can't move it centrally, when trying to change the nav I keep on getting nowhere with the location moving everywhere but the center.

**Website:** http://whereshouldieat.ie/

```
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
                    <li class="hidden">
                        <a href="#page-top"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-scroll">
                        <a href="<?php print base_url() ?>">What to Eat</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-scroll">
                        <a href="<?php print base_url() ?>#about">About</a>
                    </li>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php print base_url() ?>" title-"Where Should I Eat?">
                    <img style="width:100%; max-width:200px; margin-top: -61px;"src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/img/logo/WSIE_Header_Logo_Blue.png">
                    </a>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                    <li class="hidden">
                        <a href="#page-top"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-scroll">
                        <a href="<?php print base_url() ?>#contact">Contact</a>
                    <li class="page-scroll" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                        <a href="#login">Login</button></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Here is my css:

```
    @media(min-width:768px) {
   .navbar-fixed-top {
    padding: 25px;
    -webkit-transition: padding .3s;
    -moz-transition: padding .3s;
    transition: padding .3s;
    margin-left: auto ;
    margin-right: auto ;
}

.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-brand {
    font-size: 2em;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s;
    transition: all .3s;
}

.navbar-fixed-top.navbar-shrink {
    padding: 10px 0;
}

.navbar-fixed-top.navbar-shrink .navbar-brand {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
    }

    .navbar {
text-transform: uppercase;
font-family: Lovelo,Montserrat,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
margin-bottom: 2.5%;
position: absolute;
margin-left: auto ;
margin-right: auto ;
    }

    .navbar a:focus {
outline: 0;
    }

    .navbar .navbar-nav {
letter-spacing: 1px;
margin-left: auto ;
margin-right: auto ;
    }

    .navbar .navbar-nav li a:focus {
outline: 0;
    }

    .navbar-default,
    .navbar-inverse {
border: 0;
    }
```

I've tried changing the  to have various nav settings such as center,

addding in

```
    margin-left: auto ;
margin-right: auto ;
```

to my css for numerous settings, I've tried numerous other settings, and have even added in more css settings but it still won't work

```
    .navbar .navbar-nav {
letter-spacing: 1px;
display: inline-block;
float: none;
vertical-align: top;
    }

    .navbar .navbar-collapse {
```

text-align: center;
        }

Comment: Try removing `navbar-header` from the `<div class="navbar-header page-scroll">` element. Doesn't seem like you need that.

Comment: Thanks so much, that worked a charm!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a float style on your .navbar-header element that's from bootstrap's styles.

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.navbar-header {
    float: left;
}
```

Just overriding that seemed to work. Try using the same media query and setting the float to none: `float: none`

Comment: since doing this my navbar header is no longer

Comment: navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top

Answer (score 1):

You can remove `navbar-header` from the `<div class="navbar-header page-scroll">` element. Doesn't seem like you need that, and that class is applying `float: left`, which will keep the menu on the left.

Comment: This is so navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top stays on the top while people scroll on the site, since removing this the navbar doesn't scroll with the rest of the site

Comment: @PKGrem I checked that, but your nav wasn't fixed to the top of the browser window before I removed it, so it didn't seem like it was necessary?

Comment: I have messed up somewhere today, thanks for the help mate

Comment: @PKGrem no problem.